# How can I get "How many Network data(Mobile or WiFi) used when I call API in c# desktop application"

Tags: c#, networking, mobile, wifi, system.net

How can I get "How many Network data(Mobile or WiFi) used when I call API in c# desktop application"
I want to know How can i get total used data when i call API service

I have done following code:

```cs
if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    return;

NetworkInterface[] interfaces
    = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
{
    Console.WriteLine("    Bytes Sent: {0}",
        ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesSent);
    Console.WriteLine("    Bytes Received: {0}",
        ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived);
    lblCarrierCharge.Text = " Bytes Received: " + ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
}
```

**API CALL**

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(cloudEndpoint);
request.Method = "Get";
long inputLength = request.ContentLength;
long outputLength = 0;
string responseContent = "";

DateTime beginTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code? What's it doing right now

Comment: I want to calculate how many data used when I Call api using  
`HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

Comment: @DevEstacionPlease check my code, I have updated it

Comment: Does the `BytesReceived` return 0? throw an exception? is null? What i think you should do is save the current values of those properties. Then after your request, get them again and subtract.

Comment: @DevEstacion Thanks, it's help me alot

Comment: I've added and answer. Feel free to close this question and glad i could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute for the total bytes received per call. You'd want to save the current value of `.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived` and then after your call, perform the same call and subtract the new value to the previous one.

```cs
int previousNetworkBytesSent = 0;

foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
{
    previousNetworkBytesSent += ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
}

// perform your call here

int newNetworkBytesSent = 0;

foreach (NetworkInterface ni in interfaces)
{
    newNetworkBytesSent += ni.GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived;
}

int totalBytesUsed = newNetworkBytesSent - previousNetworkBytesSent;
```

Check if the data type is appropriate, and feel free to optimize this.